# Given the function $g$

Tags: discrete-mathematics

Given the function:

$g: m ∈ Z → |m| + 1 ∈ N$

$g^{-1} (\{1\}) = 0$ ??

$g^{-1} (\{1,2\}) = 0,1$ ??

Please correct me if I'm wrong

Comment: The first one is correct, but not the second.  Indeed, $g(-1)=2$.

Comment: @lulu It's not $g(-1)$, it's $g^{-1}$

Comment: $g^{-1}(1)=0$ and $g^{-1}(2)=\{-1,1\}$ so $g^{-1}(\{1,2\})=\{-1,0,1\}$.

Comment: I understand.  But $-1\in g^{-1}(2)$.

Comment: @lulu So we don't consider 1? But just -1?

Comment: @Kat what exactly are you supposed to do? Show that what you have written is true, or determine if it is true or not?

Comment: What?  Where did I say that?  Of course $g(1)=2$ as well and we have $g^{-1}(2)=\{\pm 1\}$.

Answer (score 0):

Given $g: m ∈ Z → |m| + 1 ∈ N$, we have:

$g^{-1} (\{1\}) = \{0\}$

$g^{-1} (\{1,2\}) = \{-1,0,1\}$