# Function counter-image...

Tags: functions, discrete-mathematics

Given the function:

$g \circ f: |n^2 - 1| + 1$

which is a composed function of

$f: n ∈ Z → n^2 - 1 ∈ Z$

$g: m ∈ Z → |m| + 1 ∈ N$

Is this correct:

$g \circ f^{-1} (\{4\}) = ±2$ ?

Comment: This is oddly similar to [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2612659/given-the-function-g?noredirect=1#comment5395566_2612659)...I assume you posted both?

Comment: This question makes little sense...it refers to $g$ and to $g\circ f$ but neither of those are at all relevant.  Your proposed values for $f^{-1}(4)$ are obviously not correct as $f(\pm 2)=3$.

Comment: Please edit this post for clarity and to show meaningful efforts toward a solution.

Comment: @lulu Edited....

Answer (score 0):

If $$ |n^2-1|+1 = 4 $$

Then $$ |n^2-1| = 3 $$

But $n^2 - 1 \ge -1$, therefore $$n^2-1 = 3$$

or $$ n^2 = 4 \implies n = \pm 2$$